# How to execute genymotion?

Tags: files

I just downloaded an Android Emulator and it downloaded as `genymotion-2.3.1_x64(1).bin`-- how do I open that? Install it?

Comment: Read the documentation that is most likely widely available through a simple google search.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3MSTD9SLy4
there you go! this will tell you how to get it, even thought i was too late lol

Answer (score 0):

Read the instructions that should be present in the same place where you found the download link.

If you can't find any instructions, you can run the [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command to see what kind of a file it is.

If the file is executable (either a script or a native code binary), make it executable and run it. From a command line in the directory where you've downloaded the file:

```
chmod +x genymotion-2.3.1_x64(1).bin
./genymotion-2.3.1_x64(1).bin
```

Given that the name contains `x64`, this is for a 64-bit PC.